# Java file extension regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to come up with a Java regex that will match a filename only if it has a valid extension. For example it should match "foo.bar" and "foo.b", but neither "foo." nor "foo".

I've written the following test program

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Pattern fileExtensionPattern = Pattern.compile("\\.\\w+\\z");

  boolean one = fileExtensionPattern.matcher("foo.bar").matches();
  boolean two = fileExtensionPattern.matcher("foo.b").matches();
  boolean three = fileExtensionPattern.matcher("foo.").matches();
  boolean four = fileExtensionPattern.matcher("foo").matches();

  System.out.println(one + " " + two + " " + three + " " + four);
}
```

I expect this to print "true true false false", but instead it prints false for all 4 cases. Where am I going wrong?

Cheers,
Don

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [Matcher.matches()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()) function tries to match the pattern against the entire input.  Thus, you have to add `.*` to the beginning of your regex (and the `\\Z` at the end is superfluous, too), or use the [find()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) method.

Comment: Furthermore, Don might consider wrapping his regex in a FileFilter:

http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileFilter.html

Answer (score 8):

```
public boolean isFilename(String filename) {
    int i=filename.lastInstanceOf(".");
    return(i != -1 && i != filename.length - 1)
}
```

Would be significantly faster and regardless of what you do, putting it in a method would be more readable.

Answer (score 0):

```
package regularexpression;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegularFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new RegularFile();
    }

    public RegularFile() {

        String fileName = null;
        boolean bName = false;
        int iCount = 0;
        File dir = new File("C:/regularfolder");
        File[] files = dir.listFiles();
        System.out.println("List Of Files ::");

        for (File f : files) {

            fileName = f.getName();
            System.out.println(fileName);

            Pattern uName = Pattern.compile(".*l.zip.*");
            Matcher mUname = uName.matcher(fileName);
            bName = mUname.matches();
            if (bName) {
                iCount++;

            }
        }
        System.out.println("File Count In Folder ::" + iCount);

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for posting an answer! While a code snippet could answer the question it's still great to add some addition information around, like explain, etc ..