# regex to determine if a file is an sql file

Tags: java, regex

I need to check if a file is an SQL file based off strings for example:

```
com/cerner/careconcepts/allergy/data/action/sql/ActivityDataReltnQuery.sql
```

So i guess a regex as follows should be enough? This works in http://regexpal.com/ but not in my code:

```
fileName.matches(".sql$")
```

Here is the code where i am trying to find all ".sql" files within a JarFile:

```
package jarreader;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.jar.JarEntry;
import java.util.jar.JarFile;

public class processJar {

public static void main(String[] args){

    //File file = new File(".");
    //for(String fileNames : file.list()) System.out.println(fileNames);

    try {
        JarFile jarFile = new JarFile("allergies-2.1.2.jar");
           Enumeration enumeration = jarFile.entries();
           while (enumeration.hasMoreElements())
               getSqlContent(enumeration.nextElement());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static void getSqlContent(Object obj) 
{
  JarEntry entry = (JarEntry)obj;
  String name = entry.getName();

  if(name.matches(".sql$")){
      System.out.println(name);
  }


}
}
```

I don't get any output name based on the above regex.

Comment: Havo you tried to debug your code? Is the filename what you expected?

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234249/java-file-extension-regex?rq=1

Comment: You may also use `name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".sql");` to avoid using regular expressions. Sometimes i prefer such a way because it's easier to understand if the reg. ex. would get more complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your regex .sql$, `.` matches a single char and after that it is expecting `sql`. So it is not matching any name. 
`name.matches(".sql$")` should be

```
name.matches(".*\\.sql$")
```

Comment: I agree with rahul. .* means any character, also more than once. \\. means 'dot' itself. you have to escape the dot with a slash (\\). In a java string you have to escape the slash with a double one (\\\)

Comment: yes, right understanding.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rahul! That explains it. Do you know how would i tweak this to get the SQL file name?

Comment: You have almost done. You can do it.

Comment: @Rookie: What do you mean with 'tweak this...'? you got the variable `name`. so everything is beautiful

Comment: I acheived this using String filename = Files.getNameWithoutExtension(path); from the guava library